# GCP assign organization policy to all except one sub-folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, cloud, terraform-provider-gcp

How to assign organization policy to in google cloud to assign a role at folder level to all sub folders except one folder.

Comment: The policy tags are specialy designed for that. What is your Org Policy that you want to enforce (and discard on a subfolder)?

Comment: I want to assign a group of users  bigqueryadmin role on folder level, but there are some folders under this main folder which I want  to exclude from this role. 
I couldn’t find predefined  organisation  policy for roles.. is it possible to fix this problem

Comment: IAM denied policy is exactly designed for that. However, it does not yet support all the permission in the BigQuery admin roles. So, you have no option for that. Do not grant the group at the top level, but only at sublevel (and I know, it's boring!)